# Wordpress Plugin - CSS not loading

Tags: css, wordpress, themes

Plugins are not loading the CSS files.

The CSS of the theme is loading just fine but the plugin CSS does not load.

<sup>If relevant, the website is: http://de.rundertisch.org/</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

wp_head(); was missing from header.php before

also don't forget wp_footer(); in footer.php before

Comment: Thanks, I already added wp_head() and didnt realized that the template didnt work with some plugin just for the lacking wp_footer()

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the style did load but wasn't working correctly. I solved it by replacing:

```
<body>
```

with

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```